# Excel Interop: Fastest way to change color of portions of text in a huge range of cells

Tags: c#, excel, interop

There some articles about the fastest way to write data using Excel interop assigning directly an Array of data to the value of the range. Like:

```
string[,] multidimensionalArrayData = new string[200, 3];
    // (...) Fill multidimensionalArrayData with your data
dataSheet.Range["A1:C200"].Value = multidimensionalArrayData;
```

There are also some articles about how to change the Font color of a specific portion of text, for example (VB this time):

```
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=3, Length:=3).Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 10
    .Color = "Red"
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
End With
```

The question now is, what would be the fastest way to change the color of specific portions of text for thousands of cells? Currently, in my C# code, I have to do it cell by cell, with a horrible performance hit. Is there a way to fill an array of 'Characters' objects in C# and pass that array to a range in one go? Any other solutions?

Comment: I am afraid for changing color of specific portions of text for thousands of cells in Excel, you will have to loop through each cell...

Comment: Sad panda face... Isn't there a possibility to deal with the interop in some way that would allow me to send a full range of cells already colored as desired at once?

Comment: Do you want to apply the `same` formatting to all the cells or it could be different? For example for `A1:A10`, the cells could have different `Start:=` and different `Length:=`

Comment: Where is the Excel coming from? Is it possible to take a step back and  say, format HTML or XML for input? You can do quite a lot in HTML that Excel is happy with.

Comment: @Siddharth: yes, every cell will have a different portion of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some months of struggling with different libraries for Excel writing, I must say that I finally went back to Excel Interop, believe it or not.

I tried ClosedXML, EPPlus and SpreadsheetLite with all the hassle of learning each library and adapting my code. After a long journey of turnarounds, bugs, sometimes generating an Excel that could not be open, sometimes having horrible performance issues or out of memory crashes here and there, I decided to try with Excel Interop again and was surprised to see that it was faster and without errors for my scenario.

If you want to try the libraries in mjb answer, do it, but I recommend you to write your Interop code as best as you can first, it might surprise you how fast it is at the end if you do it right.

**The best option for my case was:**

Use Excel Interop. Write all Excel data at once using a 2 dimensional array, then format the rich text of those cells that needed it in a second pass.

Comment: Could you please let me know which is faster between closeXML and SpreadsheetLite. My requirement is copying ranges with the styles and format. I'm using for generating reports.

Comment: +! for the evaluation and coming back to report. You should really be marking Pynner's answer as the correct one. giving yourself the tick is just stat padding.

Comment: @Anonymous Type, I did answer to Pynner's and upvoted him, but the answer is not the right one as it only works for cells with the same text and portion to color. I find a scenario where thousands of cells have different texts and colors to be more realistic, and it was also my case. I do not seek stat padding and I believe I follow the rules of Stackoverflow correctly, I am sorry if it feels the opposite.

Comment: fair enough. perhaps i was too flippant. apologies for calling you out in err.

Comment: The point is that there isn't really any good optimization for excel cell formatting for large areas of non-contiguous space. perhaps you could do post aggregation formatting of the XML file AFTER using Excel Interop to modify the 2d array of cell data (after written back to file), perhaps with a XSL post processor.

Comment: Question - how did you set all the .Colors from a 2d array? I have one filled with XlRgbColors and when I range.Interior.Color = colors; where range is my range and colors is my array nothing happens. Is that the proper way of setting it or is something else off?

Comment: @ALazyDoe, unfortunately you can't assign an array of different colors to a range. You'll have to iterate over each cell of the range, then apply the color one by one. That was precisely my performance problem 6 years ago and I had to do it that way. Not sure if this changed nowadays, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 5):

Operations using Excel Interop is always slower, more memory consume, not recommended.

Below are some of the Open Source, yet faster way to do what you need and without the need of installation of Excel:

http://closedxml.codeplex.com/ 
http://epplus.codeplex.com/ 
http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/ 
http://npoi.codeplex.com 

Released by Microsoft: **Open XML 2.0** 
*Another faster way to do what you want.* 
Download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124 
Introduction: http://blog.stuartwhiteford.com/?p=49

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there were so many options and capabilities. I want to do certain advanced things with interop tha I am not sure these will be able to handle, I'll certainly take a look at all of them. But I could also write the Excel first with these and then use Interop for whatever is not covered. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that you will gain a large performance increase with this code (as hacking into individual cells is a time consuming operation). Characters is apparently a range property, so you don't have to specify a particular cell.

You can use the following to avoid looping

```
With Range("A1:A3").Characters(1, 2).Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 6
End With
```

Great question.... I have had a number of use cases for formatting partial cells but it is a pain to do manually.

Comment: Hey Pynner, that definitely would work in a scenario where all cells have the same text or coloring positions. Unfortunately, in my case almost all cells will have different texts and colored portions. Thanks anyhow! :)